# Job failing at particular step, no exceptions logged or in console

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a baffling issue that I've been fighting with for a few days that the cause for it seems to be quite elusive. In a nutshell, I have three steps in a particular job, and the job always fails after Step #2. I've verified that the Tasklets being executed are returning as expected, the listeners afterStep indicate that the expected return value for ExitStatus is "CONTINUE", but it never reaches the beforeStep for the next Step, stating that the job has failed. I've stepped through the code to find that it fails at SImpleJobLauncher.run. I set logging to trace, and I believe I've determine where the first occurrence of this issue is logged.

```
  2017-06-15 10:24:42 [jobLauncherTaskExecutor-2] DEBUG o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute 281 - Step execution complete: StepExecution: id=3397, version=3, name=STEP THAT ISN'T RUNNING, status=COMPLETED, exitStatus=CONTINUE, readCount=0, filterCount=0, writeCount=0 readSkipCount=0, writeSkipCount=0, processSkipCount=0, commitCount=1, rollbackCount=0
  2017-06-15 10:24:42 [jobLauncherTaskExecutor-2] DEBUG o.s.t.s.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction 367 - Creating new transaction with name [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.updateExecutionContext]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
  2017-06-15 10:24:42 [jobLauncherTaskExecutor-2] DEBUG o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin 248 - Acquired Connection [jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl, UserName=USERNAME, Oracle JDBC driver] for JDBC transaction
  2017-06-15 10:24:42 [jobLauncherTaskExecutor-2] DEBUG o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin 265 - Switching JDBC Connection [jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl, UserName=USERNAME, Oracle JDBC driver] to manual commit
  2017-06-15 10:24:42 [jobLauncherTaskExecutor-2] TRACE o.s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager.bindResource 193 - Bound value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@4ab1bdf6] for key [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@58aa1d72] to thread [jobLauncherTaskExecutor-2]
  2017-06-15 10:24:42 [jobLauncherTaskExecutor-2] TRACE o.s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager.initSynchronization 272 - Initializing transaction synchronization
  2017-06-15 10:24:42 [jobLauncherTaskExecutor-2] TRACE o.s.t.i.TransactionAspectSupport.prepareTransactionInfo 474 - Getting transaction for [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.updateExecutionContext]
  2017-06-15 10:24:42 [jobLauncherTaskExecutor-2] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update 869 - Executing prepared SQL update
  2017-06-15 10:24:42 [jobLauncherTaskExecutor-2] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute 616 - Executing prepared SQL statement [**UPDATE BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT SET SHORT_CONTEXT = ?, SERIALIZED_CONTEXT = ? WHERE JOB_EXECUTION_ID = ?**]
  2017-06-15 10:24:42 [jobLauncherTaskExecutor-2] TRACE o.s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager.getResource 140 - Retrieved value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@4ab1bdf6] for key [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@58aa1d72] bound to thread [jobLauncherTaskExecutor-2]
  2017-06-15 10:24:42 [jobLauncherTaskExecutor-2] TRACE o.s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager.getResource 140 - Retrieved value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@4ab1bdf6] for key [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@58aa1d72] bound to thread [jobLauncherTaskExecutor-2]
  2017-06-15 10:24:42 [jobLauncherTaskExecutor-2] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement 879 - SQL update affected 1 rows
  2017-06-15 10:24:42 [jobLauncherTaskExecutor-2] TRACE o.s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager.getResource 140 - Retrieved value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@4ab1bdf6] for key [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@58aa1d72] bound to thread [jobLauncherTaskExecutor-2]
  2017-06-15 10:24:42 [jobLauncherTaskExecutor-2] TRACE o.s.t.i.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning 502 - Completing transaction for [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.updateExecutionContext]
  2017-06-15 10:24:42 [jobLauncherTaskExecutor-2] TRACE o.s.t.s.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerBeforeCommit 930 - Triggering beforeCommit synchronization
  2017-06-15 10:24:42 [jobLauncherTaskExecutor-2] TRACE o.s.t.s.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerBeforeCompletion 943 - Triggering beforeCompletion synchronization
  2017-06-15 10:24:42 [jobLauncherTaskExecutor-2] DEBUG o.s.t.s.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit 759 - Initiating transaction commit
  2017-06-15 10:24:42 [jobLauncherTaskExecutor-2] DEBUG o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager.doCommit 310 - Committing JDBC transaction on Connection [jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl, UserName=USERNAME, Oracle JDBC driver]
  2017-06-15 10:24:42 [jobLauncherTaskExecutor-2] TRACE o.s.t.s.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerAfterCommit 956 - Triggering afterCommit synchronization
  2017-06-15 10:24:42 [jobLauncherTaskExecutor-2] TRACE o.s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager.clearSynchronization 331 - Clearing transaction synchronization
  2017-06-15 10:24:42 [jobLauncherTaskExecutor-2] TRACE o.s.t.s.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerAfterCompletion 973 - Triggering afterCompletion synchronization
  2017-06-15 10:24:42 [jobLauncherTaskExecutor-2] TRACE o.s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager.doUnbindResource 243 - Removed value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@4ab1bdf6] for key [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@58aa1d72] from thread [jobLauncherTaskExecutor-2]
  2017-06-15 10:24:42 [jobLauncherTaskExecutor-2] DEBUG o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager.doCleanupAfterCompletion 368 - Releasing JDBC Connection [jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl, UserName=USERNAME, Oracle JDBC driver] after transaction
  2017-06-15 10:24:42 [jobLauncherTaskExecutor-2] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doReleaseConnection 327 - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
  2017-06-15 10:24:42 [jobLauncherTaskExecutor-2] DEBUG o.s.b.c.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume 183 - Completed state=JOB NAME.STEP THAT ISN'T RUNNING with status=CONTINUE
  2017-06-15 10:24:42 [jobLauncherTaskExecutor-2] DEBUG o.s.b.c.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume 167 - Handling state=JOB NAME.FAILED
  2017-06-15 10:24:42 [jobLauncherTaskExecutor-2] DEBUG o.s.b.c.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume 183 - Completed state=JOB NAME.FAILED with status=FAILED
2017-06-15 10:24:42 [jobLauncherTaskExecutor-2] DEBUG o.s.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute 308 - Job execution complete: JobExecution: id=1224, version=1, startTime=Thu Jun 15 10:24:42 EDT 2017, endTime=null, lastUpdated=Thu Jun 15 10:24:42 EDT 2017, status=FAILED, exitStatus=exitCode=FAILED;exitDescription=, job=[JobInstance: id=871, version=0, Job=[JOB NAME]], jobParameters=[{timestamp=1497536682001}]
```

Job setup is as follows. It uses java annotation instead of xml

```
@Autowired
private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

@Bean
    public Job importCostDataJob(@Qualifier("firstStep") Step firstStep,
                                 @Qualifier("secondStep") Step secondStep,
                                 @Qualifier("stepThatIsntRunning") Step stepThatIsntRunning,
                                 @Qualifier("customJobListener") CustomJobListener customJobListener
    ) {

        return jobBuilderFactory.get("JOB NAME")
                                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                                .listener(customJobListener)
                                .flow(firstStep)
                                .next(secondStep)
                                .next(stepThatIsntRunning)
                                .build()
                                .build();
}
```

The closest thing that I can figure is for whatever reason that SQL query in bold is causing the issue, but I can't see has to how or why? It's not making it as far as the listener for the failed step, so not too sure where else I could check that may shed some light on this.

Anyone else ever ran into this at all?

Comment: Could you post job xml?

Comment: @NghiaDo job setup posted

Comment: Why do you call `build` twice? Or is it a typo?

Comment: @JorgeCampos removing one of them returns an error of incompatible types. FlowBuilder cannot be converted to Job. Adding the second build resolve that issue.

Comment: Ok, you say that you think the UPDATE query is causing the issue, although it executes and even states that affected one row. I don't think that the query is the problem, I would investigate something regarding the transaction this job is executing. I would change the `stepThatIsntRunning` to do nothing first just a log the it passed there... To verify if the problem is on it first... or even not call it at all... That is to try to isolate the problem

Comment: Another thing, everywhere I look (samples) people use .end() after a flow or a step... before the build, Maybe it worth to look into it.